# Independant variable for Asprin pill titration with NaOH solution

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I am assigned to do an independently designed chemistry experiment for school. I want to do titration of Aspirin pills with NaOH solution using Phenolphthalein as indicator. I am struggling to find and independent variable for the experiment. I thought about doing heat, but is unsure about the mechanisms of that. If anyone could help me or guide me in a direction I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Independent variable means the variable which you can change easily. Direct titration aspirin is not a good idea as aspirin hydrolyzes into salicylic acid. There are a lot of non-sense high school/college level experiments doing direction titration and ignoring the side reaction of hydrolysis.

The proper procedure of aspirin analysis is by back-titration with NaOH and taking hydrolysis into account. Ask your teacher about it by showing him/her this procedure [Back titration of aspirin](http://www1.lasalle.edu/~prushan/BackTitration-lab4.pdf)

Coming back to independent variables...Just now you have another independent variable...comparison of two different methods of titration (direct vs. back). Think of other independent variables and share in your comments.